# CAML query contains does not work

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

I've got this code, which takes a part of the title to perform a query and filter part of the content of a list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var items_lista; 

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', Initialize);

    function Initialize() {

        var PDP_Link_Filter = $("title").text().split("-")[1].split(".")[0];  

        PDP_Link_Filter = "Link_" + PDP_Link_Filter + "_"; 

        var contexto = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = contexto.get_web();
        var listas = web.get_lists();
        var parametros = listas.getByTitle('Parametrizacion_WF');

        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();

        query.set_viewXml("<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/>" + 
                          "<Value Type='Text'>" + PDP_Link_Filter + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query>");

        console.log(query);

        items_lista = parametros.getItems(query);
        contexto.load(items_lista);
        contexto.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onRequestFailed));

    } //Initialize 

    function onRequestSucceeded() 
    {
        console.log(items_lista); 
        for(i = 0; i < items_lista.get_count(); i++) 
        {
            console.log(items_lista.get_item(i).get_item('Title'));
        }       
    }
    function onRequestFailed() { console.log('Error'); }

</script>
```

The query filter that it generates (obtained through console.log()):

```
<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>P000</Value></Contains></Where></Query>
```

But when the for loop runs it shows all the content of the list not just the rows that match the filter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably related with malformed value for [SP.CamlQuery.viewXml property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee549968(v=office.14).aspx). Since this property expects *XML schema that defines the list view*, the *root* element has to be `View` element, for example:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.getItems('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query></Query></View>');
```

In your case enclose the query with `View` element:

```
<View>
   <Query>...</Query>
</View>
```

Comment: I enclosed it as you suggest, but now the query does not return any data. Am I doing correctly a like query? I wanna do a select of all items that have a title name like P000. I've tried even with '%P000%' but does not work either

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  The query filter was wrong, I needed a trim(). With your solution works fine. Thank You!